# Does AngularJS have any good tutorials on how to create a simple grid?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following coded with Knockout:

```
        <form action='/someServerSideHandler'>
            <p>You have asked for <span data-bind='text: citys().length'>&nbsp;</span> city(s)</p>
            <table data-bind='visible: citys().length > 0'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th />
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind='foreach: citys'>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class='required' data-bind='value: CityId' /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input class='required' data-bind='value: Name' /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input class='required' data-bind='value: Description' /></td>
                        <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeGift'>Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <button data-bind='click: addCity'>Add City</button>
            <button data-bind='enable: citys().length > 0' type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
```

I would like to move this to AngularJS but I am not sure where to start. As you can see it's a very simple grid. It's all I need. I don't need the complexity of ng-grid.

Has anyone seen any tutorials or example of simple grids that I could use to help me convert the above to an AngularJS grid?

One more small question. I looked into using ng-grid but the things that put me off using it were the size and the fact it required jQuery. Does anyone know what happens if I don't have jQuery, will it still work? Also what's the minimum size of ng-grid. I just noticed one download like saying 800K !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting from Knockout to Angular is extremely easy. They pretty much use the same concepts in the view.

Here is the same html ( as above ) but converted to Angular.

```
<form action='/someServerSideHandler'>
  <p>You have asked for {{citys.length}} city(s)</p>
  <table ng-show="citys.length > 0">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th />
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="city in citys">
              <td>
                  <input class='required' ng-model="city.cityId" /></td>
              <td>
                  <input class='required' ng-model="city.Name" /></td>
              <td>
                  <input class='required' ng-model="city.Description" /></td>
              <td><a href='#' ng-click="removeGift()">Delete</a></td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>

  <button ng-click="addCity()">Add City</button>
  <button ng-disable="!citys.length" type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```